# Determine the number of elements in H= $\mathbb{Z}/p^3\mathbb{Z}$ who has order $p^i$, for $0\leq i \leq3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let H = $\mathbb{Z}/p^3\mathbb{Z}$.
Determine the number of elements in H who has order $p^i$, for $0\leq i \leq3$

I don't know how to proceed, thanks to anyone who has an idea

Comment: Start by writing down the *definition* of $h\in H$ has order $1$,$p$,$p^2$,$p^3$. By Lagrange theorem, what are the possible order of an element of $H$? What do you get by realizing that $H$ is a cyclic group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, any subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic, and for any divisor $d$ of $p^{3}$ there exists a unique subgroup of order $d$. Now, if $d=p$, there exists a unique subgroup of order $p$ in $H$, this means that there are $p-1$ elements of order $p$. Now, consider the cyclic subgroup $K$ of order $p^{2}$. It must contain the cylic subgroup of order $p$. In $K$, $p-1$ elements have order $p$, $1$ has order $1$, and hence $p^{2}-p$ have order $p^{2}$. So all in all, 1 element of order $1$, $p-1$ elements of order $p$, and $p^{2}-p$ have order $p^{2}$. So how many elements are of order $p^{3}$ ?

Comment: i would say $p^3-p^2$ and we verify that $p^3-p^2 +p^2-p + p-1 +1= p^3$